# Can physical keyboards really only be used with specific devices?

Tags: keyboard, compatibility, external-keyboard

The web is full of physical tablet keyboards, all of them being restricted to one (or a few) specific devices. Can the keyboards really only be used with those devices or do they use the same Bluetooth/USB/... interface anyway?
Example: [Logitech's "Ultrathin Keyboard Cover"](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/tablet-accessories/keyboard-cases/ultrathin-keyboard-cover) was specificallty designed for the iPad. Can it be used with other tablets like [lenovo's "Ideapad A2109A"](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow%3aitem.detail?GroupID=457&Code=22901AU&category_id=CBB95CCED032D3F9226567B6583B5447)?

What about keyboards that aren't even designed for tablets at all? Can generic Bluetooth keyboards be used with android tablets?

I know this question is too generic to be answered with a simple *yes* or *no*. The question is just whether they are compatible as a rule.